# protected method in abstract class

Tags: php, class, abstract

In my PHP code I have a protected method in an abstract class which we'll call class A. If I create a new class called B which extends A, do I have to simply declare it public in B or do I have to re-write all the implementation so when I instanciate B I can then call this method?

```
abstract class A {
  protected function test() {
    //do some stuff here
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public function test() {
    //Do I need to do something here?
  }
}
```

Thank you
Crouz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `parent::test()` call - or not do not declare method in child class at all. In second case method will be [inherited](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) from parent class while in first case it will be method of `B` which calls parent method, i.e. method of `A`.

Also, if you will not declare method in child class, it will not be public, so it may be not the thing you're looking for (mentioned to show how inheritance works). I.e. if you want to have public method - the only way would be calling `parent::test()` from inside `test()` method of `B` class

Comment: But if I don't declare the method in the child class, I cannot call it as it is protected in theparent. Am I correct saying this?

Comment: @Crouzilles yes, I was just typing that :p

Comment: Damn, why can't an answer be accepted straight away, now I have to wait to give it a green tick. Unfair on me to have to remember to go back to the question later as I do want @Alma to get his/her green tick for a prompt and concise response.